# Sending an email with SendGrid API and Godot

Tags: httprequest, sendgrid, godot

**Solved, code at the end of the post.**
I've been trying to send an email with Godot Game Engine using http request and the sendgrid API but I keep receiving 400 bad responses. I've tried to troubleshoot things that causes 400 responses but could not find the issue.
Here is the piece of code that I use, I only removed the auth-key from the code.

I've completed other actions successfully using the API like checking retrieving email templates.
Here is a link to the API docs : [SendGrid API DOCS](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send)

```
extends Control

var send_email_url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"
onready var http = $HTTPRequest
var auth_key = "authkey replaced"
var header_content = "Content-Type: application/json"
var email_content = '{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"outofemail2@gmail.com"}],"from":[{"email":"botemail@gmail.com","name":"name2"}]}],"from":{"email":"botemail@gmail.com"},"subject":"Hello, World!","content":[{"type":"text/plain","value":"Heya!"}]}'
    
func _on_new_order_btn_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Scenes/soft_new_order.tscn")

func _on_Button_pressed():
    http.request(send_email_url,[auth_key,header_content, email_content],true, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST)

func _on_HTTPRequest_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var output = body.get_string_from_utf8()
    print(response_code)
    print(output)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKe9g.png)

I tried a lot of troubleshooting regarding the **personalization part of the header** but it did not work, I still think thats the culprit.

SOLVED ---------------------------------
// HERE IS THE CODE THAT WORKED FOR ME:
extends Control

```
var send_email_url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"
onready var http = $HTTPRequest
var auth_key = "Authorization: Bearer INSERT KEY HERE"
var header_content = "Content-Type: application/json"

var email_content = {
    "personalizations" : [
        {
            "to" : [
                {
                    "email" : "emai_receiver@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    "from" :{
            "email" : "email_sender@gmail.com"
        },
    "subject" : "Hello world",
    "content" : [
        {"type" : "text/plain",
        "value" : "Hello Content"},
        ]
}

func _on_Button_pressed():
    http.request(send_email_url,[auth_key,header_content],true, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST,to_json(email_content))

func _on_HTTPRequest_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var output = body.get_string_from_utf8()
    print(response_code)
    print(output)
```

Comment: The `email_content` here is being passed in as a header, but it should be passed in as the post request body: `http.request(url, [auth_header, content_type_header], true, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, email_content)`.

Comment: Additionally, be certain that the auth header is in the format: `Authorization: Bearer <your_key_here>`.

Comment: Last note, it may be helpful for you to create the email content as a Dictionary and then use `to_json()` to get the json string. Then use `validate_json()` to make certain that your json is valid.

Comment: @hola thanks for the info, really helpful. I managed to do it. One issues was indeed where I passed the content and another was the formatting of the email. I will update the post with the code